# What is the use of 'max_features' in TfidfVectorizer

Tags: scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

What I have understood from it is, If max_feature = n; It means that it is selecting the top n Feature on the basis of Tf-Idf value. I went through the Documentation of TfidfVectorizer on scikit-learn but didn't understand it properly.

Comment: No, its selecting the top n features based on count (term frequency across the corpus.), not tfidf

Comment: I wanted to select top n features across the corpus based on tfidf value

Comment: Tfidf will depend on per document for a word. Do you want to sort it using `idf` values?

Comment: No I want top n words based of  'tf-idf'  values from each row.

Answer (score 0):

If you want row-wise words which have the highest tfidf values, then you need to access the transformed tf-idf matrix from Vectorizer, access it row by row (doc by doc) and then sort the values to get those.

Something like this:

```
# TfidfVectorizer will by default output a sparse matrix
tfidf_data = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(text_data).tocsr()
vocab = np.array(tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names())

# Replace this with the number of top words you want to get in each row
top_n_words = 5

# Loop all the docs present
for i in range(tfidf_data.shape[0]):
    doc = tfidf_data.getrow(i).toarray().ravel()
    sorted_index = np.argsort(doc)[::-1][:top_n_words]
    print(sorted_index)
    for word, tfidf in zip(vocab[sorted_index], doc[sorted_index]):
        print("%s - %f" %(word, tfidf))
```

If you can use pandas, then the logic becomes simpler:

```
for i in range(tfidf_data.shape[0]):
    doc_data = pd.DataFrame({'Tfidf':tfidf_data.getrow(i).toarray().ravel(),
                             'Word': vocab})
    doc_data.sort_values(by='Tfidf', ascending=False, inplace=True)
    print(doc_data.iloc[:top_n_words])
```

Comment: doc_data = pd.DataFrame({'Tfidf':tfidf_data.getrow(i).toarray().ravel(),
                             'Word': vocab}) . This is giving error , ''Series' object has no attribute 'getrow'

Comment: @Dheerajkhanna Have you already converted the tfidf data to dataframe or series?

Comment: Yes I have converted tfidf data to data frame , Then i use Selectkbest , to get top n feature .